# How to let ng-view just behind header?

Tags: angularjs, header, single-page-application, ngroute, ng-view

I created a header with bootstrap, and under that is a . The problem is, the header will cover part of the template.If I set a margin-top to the div, when I zoom in the page, the header will be zoomed in, while the margin-top won't. Is there any way I can let the ng-view just behind the header, no matter how the navbar size change?

Comment: Are you able to provide some example code?

Comment: <header> ...</header>
   <div ng-view>   </div>

Comment: Well... im guessing it might be a problem with percentage height / pixel height interference. Does the header have an percentage-based height? If yes, the margin-values does need to have aswell.

Comment: No, but I guess bootstrap make the header responsive

Comment: sounds like you used a fixed header. Create a simple html demo that replicates problem. Your issue has nothing to do with angular , it's all css